# Mobile "Clear Search History" Best Practice

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing

I'm building an iOS app. Within the app my users are searching for other users. The searched users kept and show in a "Search History" list when there is not input inside the Search Bar.

When the Search Bar is active, There is a default "Cancel" button along side the Search Bar that causing a bit of "tight" space both for the "Cancel" and the "Clear" buttons. As well, both of them sort of the same size and looks similar. The clear button is in a static position above the list, and below the Search Bar.

**What will be considered as a better UX than using the current form of "Static Clear Button"? Moving it to the center, or even use a different micro copy?s**

Illustrations:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion, but **static placements for UI elements are almost always preferred over dynamic placements**. Have you ever tried to click a link on mobile only to have an ad shift everything down?

In your design, the static "cancel" placement is the clear choice for me. The element in a consistent place where users can expect it. Instagram, Facebook, and many others have similar UIs with information in the search table below a "cancel" button.

Comment: Hey Alan! Thank you for replacing. I do have a bit of conflict that there is an "Cancel" button above the "Clear" which both of them pretty close at the location and size. Any advice on how to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes, it does from the actual app. And Sure, 1 min :)

Comment: Hey Alan. I updated the question. Looking forward :)

Comment: Is that gray box part of the UI or just markup to highlight the relevant components?

Comment: @Refe Just to markup the highlight components. I added it above the screenshot

Comment: Alan, would love to hear what your experience things is the best solution. I'm really stuck here :P

Comment: @RoiMulia I made small edits to my answer to say that your design will work! It's used by Facebook and Instagram in similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

The Cancel button may be replaced with Done or < arrow icon to go back to the previous screen. This will remove the conflict between Clear and Cancel.